.Net MAUI Label text is displaying outside of the screen instead of multiline text
I am porting a Xamarin app that contain labels inside of a StackLayout, unfortunatelly the text is incomplete and it looks like the missing text is outside the screen.
How can I display the text of the label in multiple lines?
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Start">
    <Label Text="Pain and Stress Relief"
       FontSize="16"
       TextColor="Black"
       FontAttributes="Bold"
       VerticalOptions="Start" 
       HorizontalOptions="Start" />
    <Label Text="Users seeking relief from physical pain, inflammation, anxiety, or stress."
       FontSize="16"
       TextColor="Black"
       VerticalOptions="Start" 
       HorizontalOptions="Start" />
</StackLayout>

Xamarin display

.NET MAUI display


The solution that I found was to use a Grid instead of using a StackLayout
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Pain and Stress Relief"
       x:Name="label_title_01"
       FontSize="16"
       TextColor="Black"
       FontAttributes="Bold"
       VerticalOptions="Start" 
       HorizontalOptions="Start" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Users seeking relief from physical pain, inflammation, anxiety, or stress."
       x:Name="label01"
       FontSize="16"
       TextColor="Black"
       VerticalOptions="Start" 
       HorizontalOptions="Start" />
</Grid>


Well explained here : in .NET MAUI, children are stacked and may go beyond the available space. If you need child views to fill space, switch to a Grid. https://www.telerik.com/blogs/xamarin-forms-dotnet-maui-how-layout-behavior-evolved
